# How can I set the height of tabs in Android a TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I Have this TabLayout in Android and wanted to make the tabs a little heigher than the default (48dp)

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Theme.Zhaw.TabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Here is the Style Theme.Zhaw.TabLayout:

```
<style name="Theme.Zhaw.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/text_white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/Theme.Zhaw.TabLayoutText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/text_white</item>
</style>
```

tabIndicatorHeight can set the height of the small indicator (active tab) in the tab. but how can we set the height of the tab itself?

Comment: just replace height with android:layout_height="your_height"

Comment: @HRaval java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set a layout_height in dps instead of wrap_content this could differ in different display sizes but if you wanna set a height dynamically

```
getApplication.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
```

get your current height and calculate the height according to that

Answer (score 10):

just change layout_height from wrap_content to what ever u want it to be

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="Your Value"
            style="@style/Theme.Zhaw.TabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code for setting the height of TabLayout. Hope it helps you:

```
//Get tablayout
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
//Get the layout params that will allow you to resize the tablayout
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tabLayout.getLayoutParams();
//Change the height in 'Pixels'
params.height = 100;
tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```