# Tablayout setCustomView() doesn't change tab height

Tags: android, android-tablayout

[image]

I am trying to set custom view to tab layout, but the tab is not getting the height of the custom view,so it displays cut off,can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?I tried to call invalidate() and requestlayput() for tabLayout,but that didn't help.

```
ContactPagerAdapter contactPagerAdapter = new ContactPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), new String[]{getString(R.string.received), getString(R.string.given)});
        viewPager.setAdapter(contactPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tab1.setCustomView(getTabView(0, 0));
        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab2.setCustomView(getTabView(1, 2));


public View getTabView(int position, int count) {
        String[] tabTitles = new String[]{getString(R.string.received), getString(R.string.given)};
        View tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        if (position == 0) {
            receivedCount = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tv_vouch_count);
            receivedCount.setText(String.format("%s", String.valueOf(count)));
        } else {
            givenCount = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tv_vouch_count);
            givenCount.setText(String.format("%s", String.valueOf(count)));
        }
        TextView tabTitle = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_title);
        tabTitle.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tabView;
    }
```

**tab_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_vouch_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/action_bar_color"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tab_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/tv_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_vouch_count" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**tab.xml**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_tab"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tv_color"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/tv_color" />
```

Comment: It's probably because of : `android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`. Try removing it from `TextView`s

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40239379/2196176)?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท it didn't help.

Comment: @Sunny I don't want to have a fixed size ,because I need to scaly down the numbers then

Answer (score 1):

You should refresh the layoutParams of the TabLayout after add the customView, but I couldn't calculate the new size and i used a fix size to test it:

**tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 190 ));**

```
ContactPagerAdapter contactPagerAdapter = new ContactPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), new String[]{getString(R.string.received), getString(R.string.given)});
        viewPager.setAdapter(contactPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tab1.setCustomView(getTabView(0, 0));
        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab2.setCustomView(getTabView(1, 2));

        tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 190 ));
```

I hope it helps you to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Try

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Wrap the TabLayout inside FramLayout and try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: same ,I use it to give white background color.

Comment: @KatyColins Answer Updated

Comment: its still cut of for me

Answer (score 0):

tab layout using default android hight try to put real value for it like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
..
                android:layout_height="50dp"
.. />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using it this way? if you want to use dynamic height according to the screen size of the device then do something like this:

```
private void initTabLayout() {

    tabsMultipleList.addTab(tabsMultipleList.newTab().setText("" + getString(R.string.tab_1)));
    tabsMultipleList.addTab(tabsMultipleList.newTab().setText("" + getString(R.string.tab_2)));

    tabsMultipleList.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabsMultipleList.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

> **// The line below is the real fix here it will adjust your tab size according to your screen size.**

```
    tabsMultipleList.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (2 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    //tabsMultipleList.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#0070C0"));
    int accentColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorAccent, null);

    tabsMultipleList.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(accentColor);


    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("" + getString(R.string.tab_1));
    tabOne.setTextColor(accentColor);
    tabOne.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tabsMultipleList.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText("" + getString(R.string.2));
    tabTwo.setTextColor(accentColor);
    tabTwo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tabsMultipleList.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
}
```

Comment: And just to add a bit more info I made my custom tabs for this. and then sat the settings according to that.

Comment: no not dynamically, The trick is that you need to get your device screen size in pixels and then set the tab height according to that.

Comment: Oaky ,so I should setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight to custom view height?

Comment: @KatyColins you should set that height to your tab container, if that's custom view then yes.

Answer (score -1):

Set a `layout_height` in dps instead of `wrap_content` this could differ in different display sizes but if you wanna set a height dynamically, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40239379/4564200)