# Is it possible to reduce the top and bottom padding in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am defining a `TabLayout` with a `layout_height` of `wrap_content` as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@color/grey"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />
```

This renders as demonstrated in the image below.

[image: TabLayout with non-fixed height]

Is it possible to provide some properties to the `TabLayout` – whilst keeping its `layout_height` as `wrap_content` – so that it appears more vertically compact as in the image below?

[image: TabLayout with fixed height]

I have tried setting the `tabPaddingTop` and `tabPaddingBottom` values to `0dp` but that does not produce any visual change.

Comment: you can change the height, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238828/how-can-i-set-the-height-of-tabs-in-android-a-tablayout)

Comment: @Stachu, thanks for the response. I'm aware that I can set a fixed height, which is how I generated the second image in my question above. I'm curious to know whether it's possible to achieve a compact look without setting a fixed height similar to how `PagerTabStrip` behaves.